# How to get the list of all the printers installed/connected printers in React Js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, web-applications

I am creating a web application using React Js and want to get the list of all the printers installed/connected on client machine. Is there any way to get the connected printers in web application.

Comment: Hi @Rajashree, Have you found any solution. I have similar kind of requirement

Comment: No solution has been found yet.

Comment: ok, If you found any please do comment. Thanks